# Like operation in two different tables

Tags: sql-server-2000

I use SQL 2000 server.
I have two tables; table1 & table2.
Table1 has full name, address, phone of customers and table2 has only names in short.
I want to display full name, address, phone from table1 of which name has short name (table2) in it.

Table1

```
Frank Wisely
Albert Smith
Tony Gonzalez
Peter Nicholas
Andrew Wonder
Adams Tony
```

Table2

```
Tony
Smith
Wonder
```

Results I want to get is

```
Tony Gonzalez
Adams Tony
Albert Smith
Andrew Wonder
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have more columns than just the `name` in the tables!  You'll need to join the tables, and because of that, they will need to have a column that shares the same value.  Something like this:

```
table1
------
PK Name
-- ----------------
1  Frank Wisely
2  Albert Smith
3  Tony Gonzalez
4  Peter Nicholas
5  Andrew Wonder
6  Adams Tony

table2
------
PK Name
-- ----------------
2  Smith
5  Wonder
6  Tony
```

here is how to join them:

```
select
   a.*
    FROM Table2            b
        inner join Table1  a ON a.pk=b.pk
```

if you don't have a PK type column to join on, you can attempt to join on substrings, but you most likely will get errors in your results because of false matches.  When your sample data has 6 rows all looks fine, but what happens when you have john smith, bill smith, mike smith, john brown, and mike brown?  how do you find john?  You can join table using a LIKE, it seems strange to do this.

this query will do what you are asking for:

```
select
   a.*
    FROM Table2            b
        inner join Table1  a ON a.Name like '%'+b.Name+'%'
```

working example:

```
create table Table1  (name varchar(100), junk varchar(5))
insert into Table1 values ('Frank Wisely','aaa')
insert into Table1 values ('Albert Smith','bbb')
insert into Table1 values ('Tony Gonzalez','ccc')
insert into Table1 values ('Peter Nicholas','ddd')
insert into Table1 values ('Andrew Wonder','eee')
insert into Table1 values ('Adams Tony','fff')

Create table Table2 (name varchar(100))
insert into Table2 VALUES ('Tony')
insert into Table2 VALUES ('Smith')
insert into Table2 VALUES ('Wonder')


select
   a.*
    FROM Table2            b
        inner join Table1  a ON a.Name like '%'+b.Name+'%'
```

OUTPUT:

```
name             junk
---------------- -----
Albert Smith     bbb
Tony Gonzalez    ccc
Andrew Wonder    eee
Adams Tony       fff

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: @Tony Kim, if this answer solved your question, you should click on the check mark at the upper left side of it.  This will signify that this is your correct answer.